# Disable query param in pre-request script.?

Tags: javascript, postman

I have a Get query with a few query parameters in Postman. The query parameters are really useful for quickly testing various values. You can even quickly remove and add back in a parameter by disabling and re-enabling it.

I now want to perform my tests running the Get query in a collection against a csv file.

To do this I use environment variables for the query param values so I can test for things like:
GET `http://apiBase/pathParam?qParam=foo`
And
GET `http://apiBase/pathParam?qParam=bar`

But what if I don't want to send a query param. 
Easy you say, just set your environment variable to nothing
But that only tests for 
GET `http://apiBase/pathParam?qParam=`
But I want to test for this:
GET `http://apiBase/pathParam`

Is there a way to disable the query param within the pre-request script? 
Or is there an alternative workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the command `pm.request.url.query.remove(<paramName>)` in the Pre-request Script, to remove it before it's sent.

This is a basic example using the Postman Echo service, I'm using the `test` param on the query but this is removed before sending and is not echoed back in the `args` object.

[image: Postman 1]

This time I've used the same request but changed the param name in the script to some I know isn't there and you can see the `test` query param echoed back in the response.

[image: Postman 2]

Comment: Thanks Danny - really appreciate you getting me out of a jam